# Add 1 hour to my string

Tags: c#, date, time

Hey guys working on something and not able to find the solution,

I need to make sure there is 1 hour added to this

`cleartime.VALUE = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-10-18T09:23:00.000-04:00");`

So instead of adding the time at 2014-04-23 16:30

I would like it to add it as 2014-04-23 17:30

I am soooo lost in C# Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Why did you mark this as C?

Comment: @Katana314 he did, the tag was edited out, by crashmstr

Comment: @TimS. ah, okay. Strange; when I looked, I could see the tag, but no edit history.

Comment: Won't `AddDays()` do the magic?

Comment: Are we missing something?  You have a different date in your convert then you talk about below it.  What date do you start with?  What do you want to do to it?  What date would you like to end up with?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Object-Oriented-Programming-Dan-Clark/dp/1430249358

Answer (score 2):

```
cleartime.VALUE=Convert.ToDateTime("2013-10-18T09:23:00.000-04:00").AddHours(1);
```

If this is supposed to be a DST fix, this is probably not the right way to go about it. The timezone offset should specify the right value for you.

Comment: Why not using readable form like:

    Convert.ToDateTime("2013-10-18T09:23:00.000-04:00").AddHours(1)

Comment: @iamruss Ah, that's better. I changed my answer to use that.

Comment: Definatly Look Like a Good Solution, will give this a try, Also I marked it as C By Accident. I did try the above mention solution but there are a few other line in the code and will try the above...

Comment: ok so ive tested different ways with the above solution and no go

Comment: Redid question Up Top